# Transconductance of devices

Tags: amplifier, bjt, transconductance

I wanted to ask what are the cases when it's compulosory to know the transconductance (gm) of a device, whether it is BJT, JFET, MOSFET...

As far as I know, when you want fast switching with very low timing, the higher the transconductance the faster the switch will be and in this case, is good to know it.

On the other hand, when you are designing an amplifier stage, is it important to know the transconductance of the device? Because in all the cases, you would use an emitter/source resistor for stability and liniarity, which eliminates the need of knowing the gm.

Comment: In some cases, feedback linearizes the transconductor, whether transformer feedback or other forms.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't always need to know the gm of a transistor.

Transconductance or gm is a **simplification**, or more precisely it assumes **linear behavior** of a device. So for a device that is **switching** transconductance isn't of much use as switching isn't linear behavior.

When for example using a MOSFET for switching, what is important for the speed is the charging and discharging of the gate. Which depends on the source you're driving the gate with, not the gm of the MOSFET.

For an amplifier stage it **is** important to estimate the gm of each device in the signal path as the transistors in an amplifier **are** supposed to work as linear devices.

A degeneration resistor (in series with source or emitter) does **not** eliminate the need to know gm. What if the degeneration resistor is much smaller than 1/gm, then the total resulting gm is still mainly determined by the transistor's gm and not the degeneration resistor.

You have to understand **when** you can ignore the gm of a transistor and when not. As a beginner you have to try and take every gm (in the signal path) into account. With experience you'll learn to recognize which transconductances you can ignore and which you cannot.